# How to add a screen sharing window to an ongoing video call? WebRTC

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I have a working video chat based on code like here [my videochat](https://github.com/rRaijin/video-chat-webrtc/blob/master/src/pages/Room/index.js)

I have been struggling for a long time with how to add a video track and transfer it to the 2nd user. Those. I want users to have 2 video tags from their cameras and one video with screen sharing
When I execute addTrack, how can I get it on the 2nd client and output it? In theory, pc.ontrack should receive a new video track?